# nsDialogs invalid command

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have a problem with my NSIS script in which i try to a custom page where the user insert a ClientId through the use of a textbox.

The problem I get so far is that my compiler gives my this error:

> Invalid command: nsDialogs::Create Error in script "C:*Directory*\Installer.nsi" on line 35 -- aborting creation
>   process

I have included both the nsDialogs.nsh and LogicLib.nsh in my script.

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Var Dialog
Var Label
Var Text

Name "Installer"

OutFile "Installer.exe"

InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\MyProject

RequestExecutionLevel admin

Page directory
Page custom nsDialogsPage nsDialogsPageLeave
Page instfiles

UninstPage uninstConfirm
UninstPage instfiles

Section Installer

SetOutPath $INSTDIR
File /r "*Release Folder*"
WriteUninstaller "uninstall.exe"

Call InstallService

SectionEnd

Function nsDialogsPage

    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog

    ${If} $Dialog == error
        Abort
    ${EndIf}

    ${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Hello, welcome to nsDialogs!"
    Pop $Label

    ${NSD_CreateText} 0 13u 100% -13u "Type something here..."
    Pop $Text

    nsDialogs::Show

FunctionEnd
```

I get the exact same error when I try to compile the example scripts found in Examples/NSIS.

The include files do exists, and is in the same folder as the compiler is reading them from. Is there a library file needed which is not included in the installtion of NSIS?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the plugin is missing. Make sure you have a nsDialogs.dll in the plugin directory...